# Secure Image src in ionic 3 and Angular 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a list view in ionic framework. This lists are containing image fields and the url comes from a webservices but I need to download the image with some authorization. In Ionic I am using

```
<img [src]="imgurl">
```

but this image cannot be displayed due to missing authorization. How to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of authorization are you talking about?

Comment: @Phonolog I am already using basic authorization for get image url same way for download image

Comment: @Phonolog I get the person name ,imageurl from one webservice again I download the image src from different secured url

Answer (score 0):

try `rxjs map`,  something like

```
return this.http.get(path, config).map(res => {
//authorization logic here
//return  res after passing through authorization
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the image through your own service that adds the desired authentication header. When you receive the image, then store it base64 encoded into a variable and put an inline url into your document like this:

```
<div *ngIf="!!user.picture" class="user-picture" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(data:image/jpeg;base64,' + user.picture + ')'}"></div>
```